# How to set up a basic heartbeat monitor

Tags: monitoring

I have a headless Raspberry Pi sitting in a corner, and I'd like to know if something's gone wrong with it, like it's lost a network connection or crashed. I don't need a complex monitoring or logging system, I just want a basic heart beat mechanism to get an email or other notification when something goes wrong.

Comment: I see a couple close votes for "Needs more focus"; would anyone care to clarify what's lacking about the question? I'm happy to expand on it if something's unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://healthchecks.io/ is a great tool for basic monitoring and alerting, and works perfectly for a heartbeat check. Simply [create a check](https://healthchecks.io/docs/configuring_checks/) with a relatively frequent period (I went with a 30 minute period and 15 minute grace, meaning a single skipped beat won't alert, but two successive will), and then configure a cron job to ping the check every 20 minutes:

```
#      m h dom mon dow command
10,30,50 * *   *   *   curl -fsS --retry 3 https://hc-ping.com/YOUR_HEALTH_CHECK_ID > /dev/null
```

This will alert if either the network or machine go down for more than an hour.

---

healthchecks.io also has a neat feature that supports including a [small (10kb) payload](https://healthchecks.io/docs/attaching_logs/) with the heartbeat, which seems like a nice way to include some basic status details about the machine as well. I created a [small script](https://gist.github.com/dimo414/10d6f162fb6d72f517a041d28d92314f) that sends a payload of basic system diagnostics, and will also [fail the check](https://healthchecks.io/docs/signalling_failures/) on a few other conditions such as not enough disk space.

I'm still experimenting with exactly what information and checks are worth incorporating, I'd welcome any feedback: **https://gist.github.com/dimo414/10d6f162fb6d72f517a041d28d92314f**

Answer (score 1):

On Debian/Raspbian the default application to monitor a system is **watchdog**. It is available from the repository and can simply installed with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install watchdog
```

By default it will reboot the system if some configurable tests fail. But on the [man page of watchdog](https://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog) you will find that it is also possible to send an Email:

> If the machine is halted an email is sent to notify a human that the machine is going down. Starting with version 4.4 watchdog will also notify the human in charge if the machine is rebooted.

Comment: Probably worth noting that "sending an email" this way is very far from trivial, unless it is to a user on the same machine.  Beyond that you need the services of a bona fide email server.  Which does not exist on the Pi by default, so you would need to make arrangements...nothing in the man page about that (`man watchdog.conf` is no more helpful), which implies it uses the system `sendmail`, which, again, making that work is going to be a lot of work.

Comment: @goldilocks Then the problem with sending an email always persist, no matter what application do you use. It seems to be a general problem.

Comment: The problem with any sort of local monitoring utility is it's dependent of the system being in a healthy enough state to execute the watchdog in the first place. For example if the system loses its network connection no email notifications will be getting out :)

Comment: @dimo414 *watchdog* is supported by the kernel. It's not necessary that watchdog runs as long as the kernel itself runs. If *watchdog* fails it does not trigger the kernel and the kernel do what it can in the failing state, mostly just reboot.

Comment: Sure, but there are plenty of situations (again, such as a bad network config) that are not fixed by a reboot. I appreciate the pointer to `watchdog`, but it just doesn't seem appropriate for the goal of *notifying* when the device is in a bad state. `watchdog` can attempt to fix the problem, but if it's unable to do so you're no better off than if you hadn't set it up at all.